# Publish message from Visiol Studio to AWS SNS - facing challange

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

While publishing a message to AWS SNS getting error in Visual Studio 2019

Code:

```
var snsClient = new AmazonSimpleNotificationServiceClient(Amazon.RegionEndpoint.APSoutheast2);
                snsClient.PublishAsync(new PublishRequest
                {
                    Subject = $"From Azure Function {DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString()}",
                    Message = "Testing Message",
                    TopicArn = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:dksquareup"
                }
                    ).Wait();
```

Error:
"unable to get IAM security credentials from EC2 Instance Metadata Service"

Can someone please help?
Thanks,
Deepak Shaw

Comment: I suppose you don't have the right permission configured. That is all the help we can give with this amount of information.

Comment: That error message indicates that it could not find any AWS credentials. Are you running Visual Studio on your own computer or on an Amazon EC2 instance? How have you provided it with your AWS credentials? See also: [Providing AWS credentials - AWS Toolkit for Visual Studio](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/toolkit-for-visual-studio/latest/user-guide/credentials.html)